# Reading Values from my new form in Company on CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I created a new form in company and my new form has 4 textboxes.How can i access and read my textboxes' values using web services ?

Comment: you cannot access the textboxes, but you can access that data once it is saved.  I will show you a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the Advanced Developer Extensions or XRM... here is a link to the page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681559.aspx

Using Xrm you will get a usability similar to EF and the same coding strategy can be used when you upgrade to CRM 2011.

Comment: Thx, Also can u write here a quick sample using xrm ?

Comment: The reason I sent that link is because it contains sample code.  Also, if you download the SDK, it comes with sample code.  Here is a link to a code sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681562.aspx